# Result value of elisp code stored in a file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, dot-emacs

Looking for a way how evaluate elisp code stored in an external file and pass its result as a function argument. Example demonstrating what I'd like to achieve follows:

```
;; content of my_template.el
'(this is a list)

;; content of .emacs where result of my_template.el has to be used
(define-auto-insert "\.ext$"
    ;; bellow is my attempt to retrieve resulting list object
    ;; but getting nil instead
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents ("my_template.el"))
      (eval-buffer))))
```

Probably looking for an eval-like function which besides side-effect also returns result of the last expression.

Any idea ?

Comment: (a) you should read the documentation of `eval-buffer`, without extra arguments output is discarded (b) the second argument to `define-auto-insert` needs to be a function, you could use a lambda form for an anonymous function.

Comment: You are right with the eval-buffer, I was seeking an alternate version which returns last expression result. Btw. how could help lambda as a second argument in this case - ie. evaling an external elisp file ?

Comment: I just meant you may need to wrap the calling code up in a `(lambda () ... )` so that it is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using variable to share data is easier and more common, for example:

```
;; content of ~/my_template.el
(defvar my-template '(this is a list))

;; content of .emacs where result of my_template.el has to be used
(load-file "~/my_template.el")
(define-auto-insert "\.ext$"
  my-template)
```

**Update** the function `eval-file` should do what you want:

```
;; content of ~/my_template.el
'(this is a list)

(defun eval-file (file)
  "Execute FILE and return the result of the last expression."
  (load-file file)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (emacs-lisp-mode)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (backward-sexp)
    (eval (sexp-at-point))))

(eval-file "~/my_template.el")
=> (this is a list)
```

**Update two**: without evaluate the last expression twice

```
(defun eval-file (file)
  "Execute FILE and return the result of the last expression."
  (eval
   (ignore-errors
     (read-from-whole-string
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents file)
        (buffer-string))))))

(eval-file "~/my_template.el")
=> (this is a list)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already got an idea to solve this through a variable, just curious if it can be solved in a more elegant functional way.

Comment: @DavidUnric This is my first time to heard of the result of **a file** and the result of the last expression isn't very useful or realiable, so I guess there is no existing function to do what you want, though I know an awkward way.

Comment: I didn't worked in (e)lisp but in ruby/python it sometimes becomes handy to eval file, where return value is the result of last expression/explicit return. I think it's no much less reliable then loading that file.

Comment: Btw. thanks for the update answer, although find a bit strange running whole file then re-run the last expression. It can cause unexpected troubles, if the last expression would do some side-effects. If nobody else would put a better solution, I'd mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I have updated my answer, `read-from-whole-string` is used for convert string to sexp and `eval` evaluate it, and now there is no needs to re-evaluate the last expression.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read from a string.  Read from a buffer.

```el
(defun load&return (file &optional msgp)
  "Load FILE.  Return the value of the last sexp read."
  (interactive "fFile: \np")
  (let* ((sexp  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (read (current-buffer))))
         (val   (ignore-errors (eval sexp))))
    (prog1 val (when msgp (message "Value: %S" val)))))
```